# Selenium internet explorer driver binary in json configuration

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have selenium grid and I am trying to config node that is responsible for internet explorer. I need to set location of ie driver. I can do it when I run the selenium-server via command line argument:

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -role node -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=path_to_driver.exe
```

however if I try to put this setting in config.json:

```
"configuration":
{
    "webdriver.ie.driver": "path_to_driver.exe"
}
```

It does not work. What is wrong?

Comment: You are mixing syntax. In your first code sample, `%LOCATION%` is a Windows .bat variable. In your second code sample, `"%LOCATION%"` is a literal string.

Comment: that just means path I use... I will fix to make things clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can by doing the following:

```
"configuration":
{
   ..
   "Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe": "",
   "Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe": ""
}
```

It worked for me.

Comment: If that actually works, that is pretty awesome.   Someday I will verify this.

Answer (score -1):

You can't provide the driver paths via the json config file. Those should be provide as a parameter to the command line.

Please find the list of valid values that can be present in a node json config.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultNode.json

For hub json config:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultHub.json

Comment: But why is that so? Would not be this a nice feature?

Comment: Ofcourse yes. There are lot in the world which are nice to have but not must to have :)